# Is there a python command to package all the files in an existing .blend without it being opened?

Tags: python, packed-data

I was wondering if there was a python command that packs existing .blend files, without having to open them.
For example having a folder full of 3d models with textures, videos , music,  inside, I was wondering if we could all pack with a for loop without having to open 1x1 files.

Edit:

I simply ask if there is a python mode, through a for loop to access these .blend files already saved and in the case pack all the files inside them.
I would just like to run this from a script on any project, even empty in the case.

If it does not exist, I also accept this answer, provided it is a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Blender in the GUI-less mode:

- create a new Python script like this one (I'll call it `pack_GUIless.py`):

  import bpy

  bpy.ops.file.pack_all()
- open the Command Prompt (Windows) or Terminal (Linux) and run the command `blender --b [path_to_file]/test_file.blend -P [path_to_script]/pack_GUIless.py`. You might have to put the blender path as well if you have a portable version of Blender. More info here:https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html

This will open blender in the terminal and close it as soon as the files of the `test_file.blend` project are packed, so it will be fast and clean (no GUI loaded).
If you need to do it do it many times you might want to create a .cmd script to make it easier, like [this one](https://github.com/Hilicot/blender-anticrash) I made for rendering purposes (so you edit the script with the path to the .blend file and run it, and it will do everything by himself).

Please mind that I didn't test this specific case, so you might have to tweak something

Comment: I find this alternative useful, but rather wondered if there is possibility via a script executable in blender via a classic python script

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean: do you want to pack the assets of a project in a script that is open in a different project, or do you want to do it from a classic python console not related to blender? The answer could be to use the GUI-less command I showed you in a python subprocess, I guess, but I'm not that clear on the question

Comment: I want to pack multiple .blend files by python script like addon script through any project, even empty, I would like to understand only if there is an api that allows it in blender.

Comment: No, .blender is not made to access other .blend files easily, but again, use a python subprocess. I never used them myself, but it's basically a way to start another script/program from python while the original one is still running. This way you can open other GUI-less Blender instance in background that open the specific files you want and pack their assets, then close. They will take a few seconds to do it, but the best thing about subprocesses is that you can continue working in Blender without any problem